# How to edit mime types on precise

Tags: 12.04, icons, file-format, mime-type

In precise, when I try to change default icon for a specific file type with Assogiate, there is no effects; not even if I try this operation under root rights. Are there some workarounds known for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried (in Nautilus): 'right-click' > 'properties' > 'open with'-tab ?